# jq string concatenation produces cartesian product?

Tags: json, group-by, jq

I'm trying to concatenate and output two fields in an object, but i'm getting the cartesian product instead

my input data (data1.json)

```
{"name":"asdf","loc":"lxd2","mem":332320768}
{"name":"ghjk","loc":"lxd1","mem":307908608}
{"name":"qwer","loc":"lxd1","mem":1195794432}
{"name":"tyui","loc":"lxd2","mem":269889536}
{"name":"zxcv","loc":"lxd1","mem":1578475520}
{"name":"bnml","loc":"lxd2","mem":48967680}
```

i want to produce an output grouped by loc containing loc as a header and name + mem field underneath. If i try only the name i get:

```
jq -rs 'group_by(.loc)[] | ([.[].loc] | first) + " ---------------------",("\(.[].name)")  ' /tmp/data1.json
lxd1 ---------------------
ghjk
qwer
zxcv
lxd2 ---------------------
asdf
tyui
bnml
```

so far so good, but as soon as i try to add a second field, it produces a cartesian product:

```
$ jq -rs 'group_by(.loc)[] | ([.[].loc] | first) + " ---------------------",("\(.[].name) \(.[].mem/1024/1024|floor)")  ' /tmp/data1.json | less
lxd1 ---------------------
ghjk 293
qwer 293
zxcv 293
ghjk 1140
qwer 1140
zxcv 1140
ghjk 1505
qwer 1505
zxcv 1505
lxd2 ---------------------
asdf 316
tyui 316
bnml 316
asdf 257
tyui 257
bnml 257
asdf 46
tyui 46
bnml 46
```

what i want is:

```
lxd1 ---------------------
ghjk 293
qwer 1140
zxcv 1505
lxd2 ---------------------
asdf 316
tyui 257
bnml 46
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Where do the nos, 293, 1140 come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jq -rs 'group_by(.loc)[] | ([.[].loc] | first) + " ---------------------",(.[] | "\(.name) \(.mem/1024/1024|floor)")  ' /tmp/data1.json
```

You need to address each element first and then pipe the info you want to show, you already have everything inside each single object of the array.